# Is noscript tag only generated when JavaScript is disabled?

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

I inspected a page source of my website (WordPress) application and found the following

```
<div class="control-group">
<div id="recaptcha_div" class="controls">
    <noscript>&lt;iframe
        src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6Lcc4OYSAAAAABTEzBumk7dNbnpKbpC3JhVdi2yU"
        height="300" width="500"&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;&lt;br/&gt; &lt;textarea
        name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3"
        cols="40"&gt;&lt;/textarea&gt; &lt;input type="hidden"
        name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge"/&gt;</noscript>
    <div for="cscf_recaptcha" class="help-inline"></div>
</div>
```

I believe that the JavaScript is enabled on my browser. Does this mean that the JavaScript is fully disabled or only not available at this point ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<noscript>` is part of the HTML source of the page, it comes from the server. It's an instruction to the browser: render the enclosed contents **only if** scripting is unavailable or disabled (either with preference settings, or add-ons like `NoScript`).

Answer (score 2):

The [**`noscript`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#h-18.3.1) tag is a fallback mechanism for browsers that do not support javascript (or when javascript is disabled or when an unsupported scripting language is used).

In the above case, browsers with javascript disabled will show the iframe version of recaptcha while others will use JavaScript/AJAX based version.

Note: Regarding your example, the HTML inside the noscript tag should not be encoded.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the `noscript` block is always here. But a common "trick" is to put a div in front of it with javascript.

So if javascript is disabled, you see the `noscript` block. If javascript is enabled, a div is in front of it so you can't see it (but the block is still here in the html).

Some browser also automaticaly hide `noscript` blocks when javascript is enabled. But they still don't remove it from the DOM.

Comment: »Some browser hide noscript blocks« Some browser? AFAIK this is the default behavior. `NOSCRIPT` will not get rendered, when JS is enabled.

Comment: I'm not sure that all browser in the world do that. So i prefer write "Some browser".